# Does Babel work with Matlab and how do I do it?

Tags: matlab, hpc

I want to know if anyone has manage to integrate Matlab with other platforms by using [Babel](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/components/#page=home).

- Note: I'm putting three different question similar to these about other languages that I care about.
- Note2: I did search before putting this question here. The problem is, Babel is used by too many projects and pages.

Answer (score 1):

I've no experience using Babel and not heard of it being used with Matlab before. However, Matlab tends to handle interoperability with other languages by means of its own toolboxes. In particular, if you're interested in interop between Matlab and any one of C, C++, C#, or Java, there exist mature and well-tested toolboxes for the job:

[Matlab Compiler for working with C/C++ interop](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/)

[Matlab Builder NE for working with .NET interop](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/netbuilder/)

[Matlab Builder JA for working with Java interop](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/javabuilder/)

[Matlab Builder EX for working with Excel interop](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlabxl/)

If you need to handle more languages, a message-passing library like RabbitMQ might be a better bet.